# JPanel will not show data on gui

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Hi I'm working on a project and I need to use a JTable. I sub classed AbstractTableModel and then put the data into the table. That works correctly. I create a new JTable object passing in my AbstractTableModel. Next, I make it a AutoScrollPane. When I add the AutoScrollPane to the GUI the table shows up but without any data. I'll provide short code snippets of what I think is necessary since my code is a bit of a mess right now.

```
//JPanel tableToShow = new JPanel();
    TablePane table = new TablePane(gp.txt);
    table.addData();
    JTable scrollTable = new JTable(table); 
    scrollTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    scrollTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(scrollTable);
    //tableToShow.add(scrollPane);
    //text.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20));
    //text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200,150));

    setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));
    add(jplRadio, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(plotPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

and

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


public class TablePane extends AbstractTableModel {

public String[] ColumnNames = {"Date", "Level", "Duration", "Weight"};
public String[][] data = null;
private TextImporter txt = null;

public TablePane(TextImporter txt) {
    this.txt = txt;
}

public void addData() {
    ArrayList<?> currentList = null;
    data = new String[4][txt.getSession().size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.length; i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
            currentList = txt.getSession();
        } else if(i == 1) {
            currentList = txt.getAmplitude();
        } else if(i==2) {
            currentList = txt.getDuration();
        } else if(i==3) {
            currentList = txt.getLegPressure();
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < txt.getSession().size(); j++) {
            data[i][j] = (String) currentList.get(j);
        }
    }
    //System.out.print(data);

}

//  public void displayTable() {
//      
//  }

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ColumnNames.length;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

I can provide more code if needed

Comment: `getValueAt()` must return something other than `null`.

Comment: where would I call getValue at or is that not ever explicitly called

Comment: Why not just use the DefaultTableModel to learn the basic usage of a JTable?

Comment: `getValueAt()` is called implicitly when each cell is rendered. Return a constant to see the effect, then follow @camickr's suggestion and [compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Comment: Thanks, I got it to show up.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188) to show how you solved the problem.

Comment: i have to wait 7 hours because i have less than 10 rep. Thanks for letting me know that though.